# How to use Group By, Sum, and Contains in a single LINQ query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to build a LINQ query but I'm not very experienced with it.

So far I have this:

```
int someShiftAreWanted = 
  (from allRows in aSelectedDataRowList
  group allRows by new { Availability = allRows.Avail.Contains("WANTED") } 
  into allRowGroup
  //where allRowGroup.Sum >= 1
  select 1).Sum();
```

My goal is to set my variable `someShiftAreWanted` to the number of rows that contain the string "WANTED" in the column `Avail`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My goal is to set my variable `someShiftAreWanted` to the number of rows that contain the string "WANTED" in the column `Avail`.

Isn't it just:

```
var someShiftAreWanted = aSelectedDataRowList.Where(x => x.Avail.Contains("WANTED")).Count();
```

Comment: what is the type of `aSelectedDataRowList`?

Comment: global::System.Data.DataRow

Comment: MarcinJuraszek solution is working. However I used it with the following syntax : aSelectedDataRowList.Where(x => x.Avail.Contains("Désiré")).Count();

Comment: You can skip the Where-call and just use the Count-overload that takes a predicate.